# Mapping between Java's wrapper classes and Ceylon basic types

Tags: java, ceylon

When a ceylon module imports "java.base" "8" it doesn't see the original java.lang classes, but it gets something else.

So when I want a parsing from a java string to a java integer I have to cast java string to ceylon string and then parse it into java integer.

module.ceylon:

```
native("jvm")
module mod "1.0.0" {
    import java.base "8";   
}
```

run.ceylon:

```
import java.lang{
  JI = Integer, 
  JS = String,
}



  // strange:
  // java String constructor expects ceylon strings
  // in pseudo dotted ceylon : java.lang.String(ceylon.language.String s)
  JS t  = JS("fdsf" of String);

  // very strange:
  // javas base library expects ceylon base types:
  // java.lang.Integer.valueOf(ceylon.language.String s)


  JI ji = JI.valueOf(t.string);

  // Where t is a java String.

  // strange like an elephant:
  // JI.valueOf(t.string) returns a java type.
  // for some purposes it's ok, 
  // but where can I buy the complete documentation ???
```

I'm citing [Ceylon:Interoperation / Gotcha again!](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/interop/#there_is_no_mapping_between...):

There is no mapping between Java's wrapper classes like java.lang.Integer or java.lang.Boolean and Ceylon basic types, 
so these conversions must be performed explicitly by calling, for example, intValue() or booleanValue(), or by explicitly 
instantiating the wrapper class, just like you would do in Java when converting between a Java primitive type and its wrapper class."

So, while being complicated it still works. But what can I do when I want
a direct conversion between java types not involving String.

This causes a problem, because there's no simple analog to t.string in ceylon, e.g. no "t.int" or "t.float".

So, there's a conversion between java and ceylon. But the price is high: The direct conversion (cast or parse) between java types is lost.

So please show how to achieve a direct conversion between java type (primitive and wrapped). I'm not talking about arrays and other stuff contained in ceylon.interop.java.

It's not easy to find around in the java.lang api, because type mapping rules are applied incompletly:

```
  JI ji = JI.valueOf(t.string);
```

On the one hand "valueOf" expects a ceylon input, but on the other hand it returns a java value. 
Why not the same as in the original java.lang, i.e. a conversion among java types only? Are there intuitive rules?

Could you please give a full documentation of the differences between the original java.lang and the java.lang as seen from ceylon?

How can I get the complete documentation of java.base as seen from ceylon (when not working in eclipse), generating one from reflection... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure how to answer your question, because you’re saying a lot that isn’t really a question, and then you’re asking several questions too. But here goes:

> So please show how to achieve a direct conversion between java type (primitive and wrapped). I'm not talking about arrays and other stuff contained in ceylon.interop.java.

```
import ceylon.language {
    CInteger=Integer
}
import java.lang {
    JInteger=Integer
}

shared void run() {
    CInteger ci1 = 1;
    JInteger ji1 = JInteger(ci1);
    JInteger ji2 = JInteger.valueOf(ci1);
    CInteger ci2 = ji1.intValue();
}
```

You can use the Java wrapper class’ constructor or the static `valueOf` method. To convert back, use `intValue()`.

> type mapping rules are applied incompletly:

They are not. The rules are: `j.l.String` and the primitive types (`int`, `double` etc.) are mapped to their Ceylon equivalents. All other types – including, as stated in

> There is no mapping between Java's wrapper classes like java.lang.Integer or java.lang.Boolean and Ceylon basic types,

the wrapper classes – are not mapped.

(EDIT: OP edited in a question about `ceylon.language::Integer`… that’s not a Java type, nor a wrapper type. It’s exactly what it is.)

The Java signature `java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String)` is therefore mapped to the Ceylon signature `java.lang::Integer valueOf(ceylon.language::String)`, because `java.lang.String` is mapped and `java.lang.Integer` isn’t. The `Integer` constructor is mapped from `java.lang.Integer Integer(int)` to `java.lang::Integer Integer(ceylon.language::Integer)`, because the primitive type `int` is mapped, but the wrapper class `java.lang.Integer` isn’t. This is exactly what the documentation tells you.

> Could you please give a full documentation of the differences between the original java.lang and the java.lang as seen from ceylon?

http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/reference/interoperability/type-mapping/

> How can I get the complete documentation of java.base as seen from ceylon (when not working in eclipse), generating one from reflection... ?

I don’t think this is available, though it would probably be useful…

Comment: ... and how can I parse vom java String to java int?

Comment: ... and its probably important to clarify what "mapping" means. It looks strange that tooltips in eclipse show signatures from java.lang with ceylon types. One would expect the original and then an automatic cast. I think it would be better to tell people that there is no cast - instead java.base is adapted to a ceylon environment without the possibility of type casting.

Comment: @user3464741 either `JInteger.parseInt(jstring.string)` or use Ceylon's `parseInteger()` function and `assert` the result down to `Integer`.

Comment: “mapping” means: the Java type `int` does not exist in Ceylon. When it appears in a Java signature, we represent it with the Ceylon type `ceylon.language::Integer`. When you say you expect “the original”… what would that be? `int` does not exist in Ceylon. That’s why it has to be mapped to a Ceylon type that does exist – `ceylon.language::Integer`.